# Move an oval on a chessboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a chessboard with 32 movable objects. Those movable objects are circles with a letter on it.

`boardGUI.create_oval(x0 + tileSize * j + ((1/5)*tileSize), y0 + tileSize * i + ((1/5)*tileSize), x0 + tileSize * (j + 1) - ((1/5)*tileSize),y0 + tileSize * (i + 1) - ((1/5)*tileSize), fill = "#000")
boardGUI.create_text(x0 + tileSize * j + (tileSize/2), y0 + tileSize * i +(tileSize/2),text = matrix[i][j][0].upper(),font = ("Helvetica", 12, "bold") , fill = "#FFF")`

Therefore my question is : How do I move the circle and the letter at the same time ? (First click should get coordinates of the piece and the second click should move the piece to the new coordinates)

I tried to use find_overlapping and find_closest methods of tkinter but find_overlapping gives me a tuple with 3 elements and find_closest returns me only one element so I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The code is just here to show that on a canvas there is a circle and a letter that has been drawn to represent a piece.

Comment: your code should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move both the tiles and letters at once via a system of tags. This would work by, when creating your tiles and letter objects, adding `, tag = "tile{}-{}".format(i, j)` or something of similar style within your object parameters.

Using your code, this could look like:

```
boardGUI.create_oval(... , tag = "tile{}-{}".format(i, j) )

boardGUI.create_text(... , tag = "tile{}-{}".format(i, j) )
```

Where your existing code is the same in the ellipses.

This (assuming your i and j incrementation is correct) will provide you with a way to move the tiles and letters on the tiles at the same time, likely via `boardGUI.move("tile{}-{}".format(i, j), x, y)`, where you format the i and j values with the position on the board of the tile which you wish to move, and of course the x/y values are the amount you want to move the tile/letter.

Hope this helps!